# Developer Survey is missing countries

Tags: bug, survey-2020

Not sure if this is the right place but the "Where do you live?" question on the developer survey is missing at least my country; Bermuda.  I checked the Qualtrics website (product used for the survey) and they do have Bermuda and a few other countries in their country list.

Any chance the list can be updated for the current survey?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess that option got lost in the Bermuda Triangle.